# WebServer IP address is displaying in encrypted form

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-emulator

I have created a Web Service for Android. When the program runs, it gives the local ip address of the device. It works perfectly in emulator and Samsung Note. But When I tried the same thing in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, it gives an encrypted string. Can anyone tell me what will be the issue?

Comment: using getLocalIpAddress() method I am able to get the IP

Comment: And what does the encrypted look like

Comment: http://fe80::8e77:12ff:fea5:28ab

Comment: isn't that an IP V6 address ?? I think so..

Comment: yes... then how can I connect to this device from pc? i am using a pc with IP V4. is that possible?

Comment: I could find the answer after a month [as the answer of this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286294/finding-the-ip-address-of-galaxy-tab-10-1-for-application

Answer (score 0):

You should read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses